# STM32 Wakeup from Stop mode using GPIO EXTI event

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, arm, firmware

I am using an STM32L0 series MCU. I configured my MCU to wake up from Stop Mode using an EXTI line (EXTI0 at PORTA0) during falling edge. At the beginning, it wasn't going to the Stop Mode after I called _WFE(). After tried several things I called _WFE() twice, one after another and that did the trick. Although this solved my problem I was wondering if anyone can shed some light. Maybe I am missing something.

Here is my code:

```
void HW_WakeupPinInit(void)
{
   GPIO_InitTypeDef gpioInitStruct = {0};

   gpioInitStruct.Mode      = GPIO_MODE_INPUT;
   gpioInitStruct.Pull      = GPIO_PULLDOWN;
   gpioInitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_HIGH;

   HW_GPIO_Init( WAKEUP_PORT, WAKEUP_PIN, &gpioInitStruct );

   LL_APB2_GRP1_EnableClock(LL_APB2_GRP1_PERIPH_SYSCFG);
   LL_SYSCFG_SetEXTISource(LL_SYSCFG_EXTI_PORTA, LL_SYSCFG_EXTI_LINE0);


   LL_EXTI_InitTypeDef EXTIinitStruct = {0};
   EXTIinitStruct.Line_0_31 = LL_EXTI_LINE_0;
   EXTIinitStruct.LineCommand = ENABLE;
   EXTIinitStruct.Mode = LL_EXTI_MODE_EVENT;
   EXTIinitStruct.Trigger = LL_EXTI_TRIGGER_FALLING;
   LL_EXTI_Init(&EXTIinitStruct);
}

void HW_EnterStopMode(void)
{
   uint32_t tmpreg = 0U;
   BACKUP_PRIMASK();
   DISABLE_IRQ();
   HW_IoDeInit();

   /*clear wake up flag*/
   LL_PWR_ClearFlag_WU();

   RESTORE_PRIMASK();
   tmpreg = PWR->CR;

   /* Clear PDDS and LPSDSR bits */
   CLEAR_BIT(tmpreg, (PWR_CR_PDDS | PWR_CR_LPSDSR));

   Set LPSDSR bit according to PWR_Regulator value */
   SET_BIT(tmpreg, LL_PWR_REGU_LPMODES_LOW_POWER);

   /* Store the new value */
   PWR->CR = tmpreg;

   LL_LPM_EnableDeepSleep();

   __WFE();
   __WFE();  // <------- Calling __WFE() second time works.
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved your issue by following method.

```
/* GPIO Ports Clock Enable */
__HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();

/*Configure GPIO pin : PA10 */
GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_10;
GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_IT_RISING;
GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);

LL_EXTI_InitTypeDef EXTIinitStruct = {0};
EXTIinitStruct.Line_0_31 = LL_EXTI_LINE_10;
EXTIinitStruct.LineCommand = ENABLE;
EXTIinitStruct.Mode = LL_EXTI_MODE_IT_EVENT;
EXTIinitStruct.Trigger = LL_EXTI_TRIGGER_RISING_FALLING;
LL_EXTI_Init(&EXTIinitStruct);

HAL_PWR_EnterSTOPMode(PWR_MAINREGULATOR_ON,PWR_SLEEPENTRY_WFE); 
LL_EXTI_DeInit();
```

Comment: It would be better if you said (as a description) what the cause of the failure was.

Comment: Why rising edge on the GPIO and rising/falling on EXTI?

Comment: Interesting enough implementation of HAL_PWR_EnterSTOPMode actually calls _WFE() twice (which can be seen [here: line899](https://os.mbed.com/users/EricLew/code/STM32L4xx_HAL_Driver/docs/tip/stm32l4xx__hal__pwr__ex_8c_source.html)). So I guess that's how it should be, although the datasheet doesn't say anything! I will mark this as solved.